# Share Internet through Arch Linux VM

Tags: linux, routing, iptables, gateway

I'm working with a LAN which is behind a router that I don't control. The router admin has allowed internet access to one IP address 192.168.0.50. I would like to create an arch linux VM at that ip address that I can use to share internet to the machines on the LAN as needed. It seems like this would be the default gateway for the other machines, but since all these machines are on the 192.168.0.x network, I don't know how to setup the VM to route/forward the traffic.

Everything thing that I've seen talks about using two NICs and setting the machine up as a router, which makes sense.  While a bit more complex, it seems like I should be able to do it with one NIC in this case.

Is this possible? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks much, Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NAT and two different subnets (one being 192.168.1.50). You can find loads of tutorials on how to set it up on the net. Here's how to do it on [Centos](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd.html).

Assuming you have two network interfaces, you'll have to correctly bridge them, one with the network 192.168.0.50 and one with your other network 192.168.1.50 (LAN).

If you only have one interface, you can use network aliases to set two different IPs on that interface.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...  Yeah, NATing two different subnets is easy, but I only have one...that's the trick!  I have a bunch of machines on the 192.168.0.x network, only one has internet access, so I'm trying to get internet access on the other machines by somehow routing them through the one that has internet access.